# A Proof by Induction about terms and variable assignments

Tags: logic

I am (sort of) familiar with inductive proofs about wffs, but proofs by induction about terms took me by surprise.

Prove by Induction that:

> if variable  assignments *q, q'* agree on all variables in term *t*, then
>   $$
>   \overline{q}(t) = \overline{q'}(t)
> $$

I believe I have my base case, at least:

> 1) If *t* is a (free?) variable x, then, trivially, if *q(x)* = *q'(x)*, then $$ \overline{q}(t) = \overline{q'}(t) $$

Hopefully, this is somewhat correct. But it is the next step, the inductive step, that I have no idea how to procede with. 
We have defined a term to be either a variable, a contant, or a function (taking terms). So I am guessing I now have to prove the same principle holds for constants and functions. Am I right? If so, how would one start such a proof?
(There is of course also the very likely possibility I have gotten all the above wrong ...)

Comment: For constant , you have to consider that they have **no** variables  "inside"; so the assertion is vacuously true.

Comment: Having proved the *base* case (variables and constants) you have to proceed by induction to show that the property holds for $f^n(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ assuming that it holds for $t_1,\ldots, t_n$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much. 1) So, two variable assignments will also have a constant denote the same? 2) Ok, so my base case includes both variables and constants (not just variables as I wrote)? 3) So there's only 1 inductive step, then?

Comment: A constant $c$ denotes an object $c^*$; does the "denotation" of the symbol $c$ depends on some variable $x$ ? NO. So $q(c)=q'(c)$ for every $q,q'$.

Comment: Yes; we have two "base" cases : variables and constants, and one "inductive step" : $f^n(t_1,…,t_n)$.